# Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters - Crystal Reports without database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

Our legacy VB.Net web application throws the following exception when attempting to export a report from Crystal Reports (version 9.2):

```
Exception: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException
ErrorID:   Logon Failed {6144}
Message:   C:/Reports/MyReport.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters
```

This error is typically due to database connectivity issues, as explained in similar SO questions. However, we are not attempting to connect to a database. Data values are passed in directly to the Crystal Reports engine

**Code (abbreviated)**

```
Dim dataModel As New ReportDataModel 'our data model object 
LoadReportData(dataModel)  'our method, extracts data model values from web page

Dim crReportDocument As New ReportDocument 'Crystal object
crReportDocument.Load(...)  'arg here is path to .rpt file that contains report template

Dim parameter As ParameterFieldDefinition 'Crystal object
For Each parameter in crReportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    SetReportParameters(parameter, dataModel) 'our method, sets value of each Crystal parameter from dataModel  
Next

With crReportDocument.ExportOptions
    .DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions 'gives destination file path
    .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
    .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
End With

crReportDocument.Export() ' Exception here
```

**What we have tried**

We thought this might be a folder permissions issue, since the export operation is attempting to write to the local file system. However, we still see this error when running the app pool under an admin-level account.

We would appreciate solutions or any suggestions on how to further diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a red herring. As it turns out, the report we are creating has a sub report that actually does require a data source, which me missed due to unfamiliarity with Crystal Reports. After defining the required data source, the problem was solved.